# Glide Android encoding

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-glide

I get confused how to encode bitmap with Glide. In past way, I have `private Bitmap bitmap;` that initialize Bitmap globally, and set

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

But this way consume too much memory. Then I change to,

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
       //   load Glide to imageView  
           Glide.with(this)
                    .load(filePath)
                    .into(imageView);

       //   set bitmap variable
            bitmap = Glide.with(this)
                    .load(filePath)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(100,100).get();
        }
    }
```

Everything looks good, it became faster when load image. When I have to encode my bitmap with,

```
public String getBitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encoded;
    }
```

it shows fatal exception in java, and getting error converting bitmap with `getBitmapToString()` method. Any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

```
  Glide.with(this)
                .load(filePath)
                .asBitmap()
                .override(size, size) //if you want particular size
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,   GlideAnimation anim) {
                        imageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap));
                        thumbView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: why downvoting?? Did you try this?

Comment: hey hey, I don't downvoted you. I have try that code and no work. But thanks anyway.